Display 'Per user submission limit message' as plain text rather than a warning message modal?
I am using a 'per user submission limit' message on my webform, to restrict users to one submission every 15 minutes (to reduce spam).
I would like it to maintain the confirmation wording for the submission limit message, so I have made these both the same. However after a page refresh, the plain text wording is replaced with a yellow warning modal.
Confirmation message:

Submission limit message after page refresh:

Is there a change that I can make to affect just the submission limit message, so that it continues to appear as plain text?
I thought about using CSS to change/hide the modal formatting, but there doesn't appear to be any unique identifiers for the warning model when it's being used as a submission limit message, and I don't want to affect other warnings.

The question is how to make form warning alerts look like webform confirmation messages. Do I have that right?
